# UIActivityIndicatorView.StartAnimating overriding UIActivityIndicatorView.Hidden binding

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am creating a UIActivityIndicatorView in my Controller.ViewDidLoad

```
UIActivityIndicatorView spinner = new UIActivityIndicatorView();
spinner.StartAnimating();
spinner.Hidden = true;
this.Add(spinner);
```

Then I am binding it with MVVMCross

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<TipView, TipViewModel>();
set.Bind(spinner).For(v => v.Hidden).To(vm => vm.IsBusy).WithConversion("Inverse");
```

When the View initially loads the UIActivityIndicatorView is spinning *and* visible. This is incorrect as the IsBusy property is being explicitly set to False in the ViewModel's Init(). I can see this happening and I can see the Converter invert the value.

I know the binding is properly connected because if I fire a command that updates the IsBusy property the Indicator is shown and hidden as I would expect. It is just the initial state that is incorrect.

The **StartAnimating** method seems to cause the Hidden flag to be overridden. If I do not call StartAnimating the Indicator hides and shows as expected. Of course that means I have a non animating 
Indicator.

I could get a WeakReference to the VM, listen to PropertyChanged and call StartAnimating but that seems a bit rubbish.

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading @slodge's reply I went down the road of Weak Event Listener and ran the code to Hide and StartAnimating in the View. Having copy and pasted that approach 3 times I realised something had to change so I implemented his 4th suggestion and wrote a Custom Binding. FWIW here is that custom binding

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom Binding for UIActivityIndicator Hidden. 
/// This binding will ensure the indicator animates when shown and stops when hidden
/// </summary>
public class ActivityIndicatorViewHiddenTargetBinding : MvxConvertingTargetBinding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ActivityIndicatorViewHiddenTargetBinding"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">The target.</param>
    public ActivityIndicatorViewHiddenTargetBinding(UIActivityIndicatorView target)
        : base(target)
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            MvxBindingTrace.Trace(
                                MvxTraceLevel.Error,
                                "Error - UIActivityIndicatorView is null in ActivityIndicatorViewHiddenTargetBinding");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the default binding mode.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The default mode.
    /// </value>
    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the type of the target.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The type of the target.
    /// </value>
    public override System.Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(bool); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the view.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The view.
    /// </value>
    protected UIActivityIndicatorView View
    {
        get { return Target as UIActivityIndicatorView; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">The target.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var view = (UIActivityIndicatorView)target;
        if (view == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        view.Hidden = (bool)value;

        if (view.Hidden)
        {
            view.StopAnimating();
        }
        else
        {
            view.StartAnimating();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some options you can do:

1. Subscribe to PropertyChanged changes and write custom code in the event handler (as you suggest in your question)
2. Inherit from `UIActivityIndicatorView` and write a public `get;set;` property which provides the composite functionality (calling `Start` and `Hidden`) in the `set` handler

   ```
   public class MyIndicatorView : UIActivityIndicatorView {
         // ctors

        private bool _superHidden;
        public bool SuperHidden {
           get { return _supperHidden; }
           set { _superHidden = value; if (!value) StartAnimating() else StopAnimating(); Hidden = value; }
        }
   }
   ```
3. Provide a `View` public `get;set;` property and put the composite functionality in that (e.g. `set.Bind(this).For(v => v.MyAdvanced)...`

   ```
        private bool _myAdvanced;
        public bool MyAdvanced {
           get { return myAdvanced; }
           set { myAdvanced = value; if (!value) _spinner.StartAnimating() else _spinner.StopAnimating(); _spinner.Hidden = value; }
        }
   ```
4. Write a custom binding for Hidden which replaces the default functionality and contains the combined `Start` and `Hidden` calls (for more on custom bindings, there's a couple of N+1 tutorials)

Comment: I tried number 2 but could not get the control to appear in the Toolbox and consequently could not get it dragged onto the storyboard. I then tried 4 but it looks like I need something like a ValueHasChanged event so I can respond with some custom code in the custom binding. UIActivityIndicatorView has no such events. Bloody iOS.

Comment: option 3. Thanks.