# How to properly register custom binding in mvvmcross?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to use a custom binding for UIActivityIndicatorView in mvvmcross but I am unable to get it working.
I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906367/uiactivityindicatorview-startanimating-overriding-uiactivityindicatorview-hidden). So I created the custom binder class:

```
public class ActivityIndicatorViewHiddenTargetBinding : MvxConvertingTargetBinding
{
    public ActivityIndicatorViewHiddenTargetBinding(UIActivityIndicatorView target)
        : base(target)
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            MvxBindingTrace.Trace(
                MvxTraceLevel.Error,
                "Error - UIActivityIndicatorView is null in ActivityIndicatorViewHiddenTargetBinding");
        }
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }

    public override System.Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(bool); }
    }

    protected UIActivityIndicatorView View
    {
        get { return Target as UIActivityIndicatorView; }
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var view = (UIActivityIndicatorView)target;
        if (view == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        view.Hidden = (bool)value;

        if (view.Hidden)
        {
            view.StopAnimating();
        }
        else
        {
            view.StartAnimating();
        }
    }
}
```

And I tried to register.

```
public class Setup : MvxIosSetup
{
    // ...

    protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(
           typeof(ActivityIndicatorViewHiddenTargetBinding),
           typeof(UIActivityIndicatorView), "Hidden");

        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The code that is setting up the binding:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

          var bindingSet = this.CreateBindingSet<LoginView, LoginViewModel>();
          bindingSet.Bind(Username).To(vm => vm.Username);
          bindingSet.Bind(Password).To(vm => vm.Password);
          bindingSet.Bind(LoginButton).To(vm => vm.LoginCommand);

          //Progress is UIActivityIndicator
          bindingSet.Bind(Progress)
                  .For(p => p.Hidden)
                  .To(vm => vm.IsLoading);
              .WithConversion("Inverse");

    bindingSet.Apply();
}
```

And the code in PCL library that is doing call to the server:

```
public class LoginViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    // ...
    private bool _isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get { return _isLoading; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _isLoading, value);}
    }

    private IMvxCommand _loginCommand;
    public virtual IMvxCommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _loginCommand = _loginCommand ?? new MvxAsyncCommand(AttemptLogin, CanExecuteLogin);
            return _loginCommand;
        }
    }

    private async Task AttemptLogin()
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await _loginService.LogIn(Username, Password);
            });

            ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>();
        }
        catch (SecurityClientException exc)
        {
            _dialogService.Alert(exc.Message, "Login Failed", "OK");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            _dialogService.Alert($"Unknown error: {exc.Message}", "Login Failed", "OK");
        }
        finally
        {
            IsLoading = false;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

However i have the following problems which I was unable to solve:

1. When the view loads, the spinner is visible and animating
2. When the command is executed, the spinner is not visible (I was trying version of the code with and without `.WithConversion("Inverse");`
3. When I put breakpoint into SetValueImpl method in ActivityIndicatorViewHiddenTargetBinding class, is not hit.

I am new to both mvvmcross and Xamarin. Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with the code?